# Python 3 is crashing in Ubuntu 17.10 when using Firefox v57

Tags: apt, python, 17.10, pgadmin

While I was using firefox 57, python crashed and took a while to come back. Here's the apport report.

```
ProblemType: Crash
DistroRelease: Ubuntu 17.10
Package: apport-gtk 2.20.7-0ubuntu3.4
ProcVersionSignature: Ubuntu 4.13.0-16.19-generic 4.13.4
Uname: Linux 4.13.0-16-generic x86_64
ApportVersion: 2.20.7-0ubuntu3.4
Architecture: amd64
CrashCounter: 1
CurrentDesktop: GNOME
Date: Tue Nov 21 11:23:58 2017
ExecutablePath: /usr/share/apport/apport-gtk
InstallationDate: Installed on 2017-09-20 (62 days ago)
InstallationMedia: Ubuntu 17.04 "Zesty Zapus" - Release amd64 (20170412)
InterpreterPath: /usr/bin/python3.6
PackageArchitecture: all
ProcCmdline: /usr/bin/python3 /usr/share/apport/apport-gtk
ProcEnviron:
 LANGUAGE=en_IN:en
 PATH=(custom, no user)
 XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=<set>
 LANG=en_IN
 SHELL=/bin/bash
Python3Details: /usr/bin/python3.6, Python 3.6.3, python3-minimal, 3.6.3-0ubuntu2
PythonArgs: ['/usr/share/apport/apport-gtk']
PythonDetails: /usr/bin/python2.7, Python 2.7.14, python-minimal, 2.7.14-2ubuntu1
SourcePackage: apport
Title: apport-gtk crashed with TypeError in run_crashes(): '>' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'NoneType'
UpgradeStatus: Upgraded to artful on 2017-10-24 (28 days ago)
UserGroups: adm cdrom dip lpadmin plugdev sambashare sudo
```

Please see following bug for logs and other information:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apport/+bug/1733581

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pgadmin3/+bug/1733585

Java and PgAdmin are also crashing on Ubuntu 17.10.

Am I missing any packages that needs upgrade/update?

Comment: Can you ask a question ?

Comment: @Guy.D Apologies! I have updated the question. Thanks!

Comment: now it is easier to answer. was it during a script run ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That actually suggests it was Apport that crashed. Apport is Ubuntu's crash-handler and bug reporter... So that's awkward. It would have been running to report another bug. File a bug the next time this pops up (or keep #1733581 if that's yours) but this is likely just one of those things that happens. I doubt we can help much if this was a one-off. It's not a bad report, just an odd one.

If this *keeps* happening, perhaps there's an incomplete report that's stuck in the system because Apport can't parse it. You could run the following:

```
/usr/bin/python3 -c 'import apport; print(apport.fileutils.get_new_system_reports())'
```

And that would likely give you the location of the pending reports. You could *probably* safely delete those reports but just double-check by leaving a comment with what the above finds first.

If you can't tell, there's a lot of "if" and "maybe" and "probably" in this post. It's hard to debug remotely. But this has nothing to do with Python itself, or Firefox.

Comment: we will try. However, I have reported another one, pgadmin(GUI for postgres Database) is also crashing. Anyways, thanks for the useful pointers. Appreciate the same